# Arduino with WS2812 using Adafruit NeoPixel library fade in/out different patterns

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, led, arduino-ide, adafruit

Hey all I have been trying to figure out a way to random set patterns for my fade in/ out code below:

```
int PIN = 3;
int totalLEDs = 11;
int ledFadeTime = 5;

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(totalLEDs, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
}

void loop() {
  rgbFadeInAndOut(0, 0, 255, ledFadeTime); // Blue
}

void rgbFadeInAndOut(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue, uint8_t wait) {
  for(uint8_t b = 0; b <255; b++) {
     for(uint8_t i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i, red * b/255, green * b/255, blue * b/255);
     }

     strip.show();
     delay(wait);
  };

  for(uint8_t b=255; b > 0; b--) {
     for(uint8_t i = 0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i, red * b/255, green * b/255, blue * b/255);
     }
     strip.show();
     delay(wait);
  };
};
```

The code above works great. Fades the blue in and out infinity times. However, I am wanting random LEDs to be off or have a lighter/darker shade of the color I choose (in the above it's blue).

Example:

```
[off][blue][blue][off][off][dark blue][blue][off][dark blue][dark blue][off]
[blue][blue][blue][dark blue][off][blue][dark blue][blue][dark blue][off][off]
etc etc...
```

Would anyone happen to have code already like this?

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make randomly-changing colours for the whole strip, change:

```
void loop() {
  rgbFadeInAndOut(0, 0, 255, ledFadeTime); // Blue
}
```

to:

```
void loop() {
  rgbFadeInAndOut(random (256), 
                  random (256), 
                  random (256), ledFadeTime); // random colour
}
```

---

If you want to make individual pixels different colours you could set up an array of colours, randomly initialize it, and use that. Like this:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

int PIN = 3;
int totalLEDs = 11;
int ledFadeTime = 5;

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(totalLEDs, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
}

void loop() {
  rgbFadeInAndOut(ledFadeTime);
}

void rgbFadeInAndOut(uint8_t wait) {

  uint8_t red [totalLEDs];
  uint8_t green [totalLEDs];
  uint8_t blue [totalLEDs];

  // randomly set each colour
  for (int i = 0; i < totalLEDs; i++)
    {
    red [i] = random(256);
    green [i] = random(256);
    blue [i] = random(256);
    }

  for(uint8_t b = 0; b <255; b++) {
     for(uint8_t i=0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i, red [i] * b/255, green [i] * b/255, blue [i] * b/255);
     }

     strip.show();
     delay(wait);
  }

  for(uint8_t b=255; b > 0; b--) {
     for(uint8_t i = 0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
        strip.setPixelColor(i, red [i] * b/255, green [i] * b/255, blue [i] * b/255);
     }
     strip.show();
     delay(wait);
  }
}
```