# Multiple RGB LEDs

Tags: led

I'm quite new to these things and I need some help. I'm building a computer shelf with plexiglass and RGB LEDs (one per length) and I need some help to sketch up a data sheet of some sort for this.

I'm thinking of using an Arduino Uno, but will it be able to run 12+ LEDs?

Comment: A key piece of information is how many is "12+ leds"? Is it 13, 14, 100? Without that it is quite hard to give advice? What do you want to do that a cheap, off-the-shelf, RGB LED controller can't do?

Comment: Well basicly what I'm hoping for is to control two shelves with led which then means 12x2. As mentioned I'm very inexperienced with this so I though it would be the better solution to use a arduino. Do you have any other recommendations instead?

Comment: Just get some rgb-led-strips. Connect them to and Arduino using some mosfets.

Comment: If all you want is some lighting effects, then I'd suggest some LED strips with controller and remote control from one of the well-known e-stores. You can get a power-supply, remote control and RGB LEDs at a reasonable cost. For 24 LEDs, you'll need a separate power supply anyway; the Arduino isn't enough. If what you want to do is learn about Arduino, I'd recommend jwpat7's advice. Try to get some Ws2812b RGB LEDs on a strip, and a power supply, and experiment with [Adafruit's NeoPixel library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel)

Comment: @Green, imho, there are millions of projects/tutorials on this, which are often much more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

If your RGB LEDs are [WS2812-style, 5050-size](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=WS2812+7++5050++Round&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR2.TRC0.A0.H0.XWS2812+++5050++.TRS0&_nkw=WS2812+++5050++&_sacat=0) units, it is no problem to control dozens of them using an Arduino Uno or several other models of Arduinos.  [For ATtiny systems, other libraries than [Adafruit's NeoPixel](http://www.adafruit.com/category/168) may be needed; the NeoPixel library keeps several bytes of state data per pixel, which some other libs don't.]

WS2812-style LEDs typically are arranged in serial strings, driven by a single IO pin from an Arduino.

If you have more than half a dozen WS2812s in the string, power for them should come from an external power supply, rather than via an Arduino's built-in 5V regulator.

For more information, see related questions like *[Arduino with WS2812 using Adafruit NeoPixel library fade in/out different patterns](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/10357)*, and *[Arduino and WS2812 RGB LED Strip "freezing"](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/17940)*, and  *[fading colors on a ws2812 strip](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/13136)*; also see [Google search Arduino Stackexchange for WS2812](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&q=site:arduino.stackexchange.com/questions+WS2812+-newest+-recently).